# Room frozen: what is the procedure to unfreeze it again

Tags: support, chat

This room is frozen because we didn't post anything in it for a long time. I want to make it active again. So what's the procedure to unfreeze it?

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124354/memes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no procedure  for unfreezing a room. If you have a room you'd like unfrozen, I'd suggest just flagging the "This room has been frozen" message with a moderator flag asking for it to be unfrozen.